# Menu / sidebar with interactive buttons inside item

Tags: qt

A picture is worth thousand words. This is menu / sidebar which I want to get:
[image: Menu]

Note that it is fake. This is just static QTreeWidget preparation with 3 columns, colspan and header hidden.

Nedded features:

- Grayed upper case items should not be possible to select (partly could be solved by QTreeWidgetItem::setFlags(ItemIsSelectable))
- Icons on the right side (open, eject) should be interactive. I mean click signal and cursor should change to "hand" when mouse is over these icons
- When resizing menu / sidebar using QSplitter then icons on the right side should anchor to the right edge

I'm beginner in Qt Framework but not such lame. I studied examples to find interesting solutions but I'm not sure which will be the easiest:

- Play with QGraphicsView
- Create QToolButton descendant and try to add child buttons. Then put everything into QWidget, add labels, layout and prepare stylesheet to imitate QTreeWidget
- Create QTreeWidget descendant and play with painter, mouse move event etc.

Any suggestions or other solutions? Never tried QML / QtQuick, had no time to learn it but maybe I could use QDeclarativeView or QQuickWidget

Comment: hey could you post the code for your implementation in the image somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you decide to go QML (which I would recommend, unless you have specific reasons not to) here's what you could do.

- Step one: Use a ListView with section headers: http://web.archive.org/web/20181206232533/http://qmlbook.github.io:80/en/ch06/index.html
- Step two: Create an item delegate with multiple actions / subitems.

Just take a look at the Qml docs and examples or the QML Book linked above to understand the basics of the model, ListView and delegate concepts:

http://qmlbook.github.io/en/ch06/index.html#

As to anchoring, you can do that pretty easily too by using the anchors property and the many layout options QML gives you:

http://qmlbook.github.io/en/ch04/index.html#positioning-elements

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use Drawers and Listview in conjunction to get your results. QML Drawers are the slidable widgets which you can program to open() on a click or a press event.

Here is the official write up on QML Drawer

https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.7/qml-qtquick-controls2-drawer.html

The following example from Qt runs exactly what is mentioned in the question.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-gallery-example.html

Taken straight from the code just to give you an Idea :

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.0
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
id: window
width: 360
height: 520
visible: true
title: "Qt Quick Controls 2"

Settings {
    id: settings
    property string style: "Default"
}

header: ToolBar {
    Material.foreground: "white"

    RowLayout {
        spacing: 20
        anchors.fill: parent

        ToolButton {
            contentItem: Image {
                fillMode: Image.Pad
                horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Image.AlignVCenter
                source: "qrc:/images/drawer.png"
            }
            onClicked: drawer.open()
        }

        Label {
            id: titleLabel
            text: "Gallery"
            font.pixelSize: 20
            elide: Label.ElideRight
            horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        ToolButton {
            contentItem: Image {
                fillMode: Image.Pad
                horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Image.AlignVCenter
                source: "qrc:/images/menu.png"
            }
            onClicked: optionsMenu.open()

            Menu {
                id: optionsMenu
                x: parent.width - width
                transformOrigin: Menu.TopRight

                MenuItem {
                    text: "Settings"
                    onTriggered: settingsPopup.open()
                }
                MenuItem {
                    text: "About"
                    onTriggered: aboutDialog.open()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Drawer {
    id: drawer
    width: Math.min(window.width, window.height) / 3 * 2
    height: window.height

    ListView {
        id: listView
        currentIndex: -1
        anchors.fill: parent

        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            width: parent.width
            text: model.title
            highlighted: ListView.isCurrentItem
            onClicked: {
                if (listView.currentIndex != index) {
                    listView.currentIndex = index
                    titleLabel.text = model.title
                    stackView.replace(model.source)
                }
                drawer.close()
            }
        }

        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { title: "BusyIndicator"; source: "qrc:/pages/BusyIndicatorPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "Button"; source: "qrc:/pages/ButtonPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "CheckBox"; source: "qrc:/pages/CheckBoxPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "ComboBox"; source: "qrc:/pages/ComboBoxPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "Dial"; source: "qrc:/pages/DialPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "Delegates"; source: "qrc:/pages/DelegatePage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "Drawer"; source: "qrc:/pages/DrawerPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "Frame"; source: "qrc:/pages/FramePage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "GroupBox"; source: "qrc:/pages/GroupBoxPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "Menu"; source: "qrc:/pages/MenuPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "PageIndicator"; source: "qrc:/pages/PageIndicatorPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "Popup"; source: "qrc:/pages/PopupPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "ProgressBar"; source: "qrc:/pages/ProgressBarPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "RadioButton"; source: "qrc:/pages/RadioButtonPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "RangeSlider"; source: "qrc:/pages/RangeSliderPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "ScrollBar"; source: "qrc:/pages/ScrollBarPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "ScrollIndicator"; source: "qrc:/pages/ScrollIndicatorPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "Slider"; source: "qrc:/pages/SliderPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "SpinBox"; source: "qrc:/pages/SpinBoxPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "StackView"; source: "qrc:/pages/StackViewPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "SwipeView"; source: "qrc:/pages/SwipeViewPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "Switch"; source: "qrc:/pages/SwitchPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "TabBar"; source: "qrc:/pages/TabBarPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "TextArea"; source: "qrc:/pages/TextAreaPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "TextField"; source: "qrc:/pages/TextFieldPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "ToolTip"; source: "qrc:/pages/ToolTipPage.qml" }
            ListElement { title: "Tumbler"; source: "qrc:/pages/TumblerPage.qml" }
        }

        ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
    }
}
```

ToolButton with drawer.png as Image, is programmed to open and close the sidebar.

I hope this helps.